# Как определить namespace во фреймворке?

Tags: php

Использую cakephp версии 3.3. Конкретно для функционала приложения хочу определить папку Kernel, где будет реализация нужных мне вещей, структура папок такова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В abstractVideoContent написал абстрактный класс и добавил в начале скрипта namespace App\Kernel;
В Реализации RandomVideoContent прописал тот же самый namespace. Дальше в файле MainController прописал use App\Kernel; И попытался создать экземпляр класса RandomVideoContent, но вышла ошибка, что класс не найден, скажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `composer.json` надо добавить такую строчку:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Cake\\": "src",
        "App\\Kernel\\": "src/Kernel" // новая строчка
    },
    ...
},
...
```

После этого перегенерировать `autoload.php`:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Нет, такое мне не помогло

Comment: Какое полное название класса в ошибке?

Comment: Class 'App\Controller\RandomVideoContent' not found

Comment: Значит создаете вы его из-под контроллера указывая относительное имя - ``new RandomVideoContent()``. А это неправильно. Напишите  ``new \App\Kernel\RandomVideoContent()``

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, на что получил результат: Class 'App\Kernel\RandomVideoContent' not found

Comment: Значит что-то упустили. Проверьте ``composer.json`` и ``vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php``.

Comment: Нашел проблему, оказывается не заметил ошибку в названии файла RandomVideoContent, спасибо за помощь